# Laravel - How to move file from local storage to another storage?

Tags: php, laravel, file, storage, fopen

My goal is to upload a large file to dropbox and because the waiting time can be too long I want to split the process and upload the file through a queue.

I'm doing the following:

- I upload a file (that can be large)
- I save it on local storage
- I save data about the file in database.
- In a queue I want to get the file and move it to a dropbox disk.

The problem is that when I do the last step I get the following error

```
ErrorException
fopen(files/7u7v6LYq72vmXLqeWPsc6b0khiy9pEbFicVJuK2W.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I tried different approaches but I can't find a solution.

**My code**

Controller method:

```
public function uploadToDropbox(Request $request){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,doc,docx,pdf,txt,mp3,mp4,avi|max:600000',
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
        ]);

        /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $data['file'];

        $path = Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs( 'file', $uploadedFile, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());

        $file = new File();
        $file->first_name = $data['first_name'];
        $file->last_name = $data['last_name'];
        $file->file = $path;
        $file->original_name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->size = $uploadedFile->getSize();
        $file->real_path = $uploadedFile->getRealPath();
        $file->save();

        $result = ProcessFile::dispatch($file);

        if($result){
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg'=>'Successfully file uploaded']);
        } else {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg'=>'File failed to upload']);
        }
}
```

Queue job:

```
public function handle()
{
        if (Storage::disk('local')->exists($this->file->file)) {
            $name = strtolower($this->file->first_name) . '_' . strtolower($this->file->last_name);

            $rez = Storage::disk('dropbox')->putFileAs(
                'challenge-files/' . $name . '/',
                $this->file->file,
                $this->file->original_name
            );

            Log::info('message: ' . $rez);
        } else {
            Log::alert('falseeeee');
        }
}
```

FilesystemAdapter puthFileAs method:

```
public function putFileAs($path, $file, $name, $options = [])
{
        $stream = fopen(is_string($file) ? $file : $file->getRealPath(), 'r');

        // Next, we will format the path of the file and store the file using a stream since
        // they provide better performance than alternatives. Once we write the file this
        // stream will get closed automatically by us so the developer doesn't have to.
        $result = $this->put(
            $path = trim($path.'/'.$name, '/'), $stream, $options
        );

        if (is_resource($stream)) {
            fclose($stream);
        }

        return $result ? $path : false;
}
```

filesystems.php local disk configs

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'permissions' => [
                'file' => [
                    'public' => 0664,
                    'private' => 0600,
                ],
                'dir' => [
                    'public' => 0775,
                    'private' => 0700,
                ],
            ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you haven't modify the permissions mappings in your filesystems configuration file.

Look for the

> dir

array and check if the

> public

number is

> 0775

if it is not, change it to that number
Look for

> file

change `'public' => 0664`

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I found the issue. The problem is that the path is relative. After adding 'storage/app/' it worked. Thank you!